# .NET Core worker service freezing

Tags: c#, .net-core, service

We have a long running .net core worker service which has been in production for over 6 months now without any problem. Now 2nd of January it just froze after midnight and just stood there doing nothing.

We have daily log file and 1. day has last entry at 2022-01-01T23:15:38. Second day doesn't have logfile at all.

As the service is "running" our monitoring didn't notice anything wrong.

So on third days morning we notice that our service is frozen and restart it.
Fourth day it works as intended until midnight, last entry in log is 2022-01-04T23:47:55
and service has frozen again. No log file for 5th day, until I restart it again.

So has anyone experienced similar behavior?

Comment: I suggest you use Visual Studio remote debugging (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2022) to attach to the frozen process. From there you can look at the threads etc to work out what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, forgot totally that option, just have to wake after midnight to check if its frozen so I can get it running before 3AM.

Answer (score 0):

So I updated all nuget packages, published and deployed and problem disappeared.
Also Visual Studio had several update since this application was last deployed. So something somewhere was updated that fixed this issue.

Comment: I am running into a similar problem @Jyri did you solve your issue?

Comment: I updated all nuget packages and rebuild it with latest visual studio updates. It has after that worked well